# Grouped Shapes / Outlines (Almost) Disappear After Creating Pattern?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, patterns, outline

I've selected a bunch of shapes and outlines for a pattern. I've gone to Object > Group, to group them all together, dragged them to the swatches panel to create a new swatch, and then after double-clicking that swatch, it brings up the Pattern Options panel. After approving the settings and clicking 'Done', the pattern is completely ruined, with most of the shapes reduced to a couple lines or nothing at all:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Why does this happen? Do all of the outlines need to be converted to shapes (i.e. outlined strokes) beforehand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that yes, outlining all strokes in order to convert them to shapes prevents them from disappearing after creating a pattern. However, now I'm not able to create a pattern at all. I've selected my grouped objects, and the pattern options panel is greyed out:

[image]

Also, if a try to drag and drop the shapes into the Swatches panel, nothing happens. No new swatch gets created.

**EDIT**

Finally - what worked from me was to select all of the objects for my pattern and then click on the 'new swatch' icon in the swatches panel. I'm now able to create patterns by expanding a random shape with that swatch selected:

[image]

Comment: Glad you got it to work somehow- I suggest the issue is with your construction rather than the pattern making part. You do not need to Group or Expand prior to making the  Pattern.